# Django rest framework - add secondary order to OrderingFilter

Tags: sorting, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I'm using DRF OrderingFilter ordering_fields for sorting my ListAPIView:

```
ordering_fields = ('close_date')
```

The problem is that there are rows with the same 'close_date' and the order is not the same each time, therefore I want to add secondary sort for each call. so in each query the data will be sorted by 'close_date' AND 'id'

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#specifying-a-default-ordering), you can set default order using `ordering` param with several fields

```
class YourListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    ...
    ordering = ['close_date', 'id']
```

Comment: @weAreStartDust, in case 'ordering' is different than 'ordering_fields'- will the query will be sorted by both of them?

Comment: `ordering_fields` responsible for fields that user **can** filter, and `ordering` responsible for ordering by default, [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#specifying-which-fields-may-be-ordered-against). So query will be sorted by `ordering`